# Querying a selected options' dataset not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select dropdown list like this:

```
var itemInfo = ($(this).children('option:selected').data('name'));

console.log(itemInfo);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="delivery-options" class="custom-select">
<option selected="" value="0">VÁLASSZON!</option>
<option value="1790" data-price="1790" data-name="MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel" data-id="4TB994cA318NHg6u8ILM">MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;790&nbsp;Ft</option>
<option value="990" data-price="990" data-name="Foxpost automatába" data-id="cC62JjhpDE7ksFd6A2jd">Foxpost automatába - 990&nbsp;Ft</option>
<option value="1611" data-price="1611" data-name="GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel" data-id="i5lwg116QsFzTuuSuxBk">GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;611&nbsp;Ft</option>
</select>
```

Based on the info that I found here in StackOverflow I've tried:

This works:

```
var itemInfo = ($(this).children('option:selected').data('name'));
```

These returns undefined:

```
var itemInfo = ($(this).children('option:selected').dataset);
var itemInfo = ($(this).children('option:selected').dataset[0]);
```

What is the proper way? I need the whole dataset as an object.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var itemInfo = $(this).children('option:selected').data();
```

It will get the entire data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("option:selected",this)` and `.data()`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#delivery-options").on("change",function() {
    console.log($("option:selected",this).data())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="delivery-options" class="custom-select">
  <option selected="" value="0">VÁLASSZON!</option>
  <option value="1790" data-price="1790" data-name="MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel" data-id="4TB994cA318NHg6u8ILM">MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;790&nbsp;Ft</option>
  <option value="990" data-price="990" data-name="Foxpost automatába" data-id="cC62JjhpDE7ksFd6A2jd">Foxpost automatába - 990&nbsp;Ft</option>
  <option value="1611" data-price="1611" data-name="GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel" data-id="i5lwg116QsFzTuuSuxBk">GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;611&nbsp;Ft</option>
</select>
```

Vanilla JS:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("delivery-options").addEventListener("change",function() {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="delivery-options" class="custom-select">
  <option selected="" value="0">VÁLASSZON!</option>
  <option value="1790" data-price="1790" data-name="MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel" data-id="4TB994cA318NHg6u8ILM">MPL küldemény előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;790&nbsp;Ft</option>
  <option value="990" data-price="990" data-name="Foxpost automatába" data-id="cC62JjhpDE7ksFd6A2jd">Foxpost automatába - 990&nbsp;Ft</option>
  <option value="1611" data-price="1611" data-name="GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel" data-id="i5lwg116QsFzTuuSuxBk">GLS háztól-házig futár előre fizetéssel - 1&nbsp;611&nbsp;Ft</option>
</select>
```